# Getting the index of the current item in for each arrow function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a better way to get the current index in a for each arrow function:

```
var index = 0
//format json data
out.eptime.forEach(item =>
index++     
console.log(item));
```

Comment: The forEach method gives you 3 parameters: (current_item, index_of_current_item, complete_array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use index param in foreach function

```
out.eptime.forEach((item, index) => console.log(item));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the second parameter of the callback function of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). This supplies the index.

You may have a look to the syntax:

> ```
> arr.forEach(callback(currentValue [, index [, array]])[, thisArg]);
> ```

```js
['a', 'b'].forEach((item, index) => console.log(index, item));
```